# Basic Shipping Calculator

Tags: javascript, php

I need to calculate price of shipping every 500g. I need it in Javascript or PHP. Please help me out figure it. For Eg: Lets take the base price of Rs 40 and the Base weight as 500g. So if I enter 250g it should say 40 and If I enter 850g then it should say Rs 80 and it goes on like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the price with:

```
ceil(weight / baseWeight) * basePrice
```

In your first example:

```
ceil(250 / 500) * 40 = ceil(0.5) * 40 = 1 * 40 = 40
```

In your second example:

```
ceil(850 / 500) * 40 = ceil(1.7) * 40 = 2 * 40 = 80
```

`ceil` is a common function in most programming languages: [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php), [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

Be aware of integer division in some programming languages and make sure that `250 / 500` returns `0.5` and not `0`.

Also rounding errors can occur.

Comment: I have another question. If the base price is 200 and base weight is 10kg and I want to calculate per kg after 10kgs. So per kg price will be Rs 20. So how do we do that ?

Comment: @GanpatthRadjane There is no difference. If weight > 10 kg: `200 + ceil(weight - 10) * 20`.

Comment: @imposterSyndrome Hey, I am new to PHP which is why I raised the question. Its not that I didnt want to work it out. I tried but I couldnt find enough resources in the internet so I raised a question in Stackoverflow. If you know something and if you are lazy then nobody will help

Comment: @jabaa thank you so much. This means a lot to me

Comment: @imposterSyndrome For me this looks like a very specific mathematical problem. How to calculate the values of a step function? I intentionally didn't provide code but only the mathematics. Without mathematical background it can be pretty difficult to even start searching about this topic. If you know that this is a rounded linear equation it seems like a trivial question but if you don't know anything about it it's almost impossible to solve it.

Comment: Hey, The 10kg thing is not what I wanted actually. If I put 1 as the weight then it has to show 200 instead it shows 24. What to do?

Comment: @GanpatthRadjane You should ask a new question, post your code, describe why it doesn't work and what you've tried to solve it.